Databricks RAG GEN Ai Classroom Setup
I'm trying to initiate the databricks Classroom Setup, 2.1 - Preparing Data for RAG, The course from databricks Data Eng with GENAI, whenever i run it says : Note: you may need to restart the kernel using %restart_python or dbutils.library.restartPython() to use updated packages.
I tried to do each and everything.
I tried to install individually and refreshing, removing caches

What is error or blockers you are facing. Please add those details

what is the problem you are facing?
